# Matplotlib bar() function always raises Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am using this very simple code to test creation of a Bar plot.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
vec = np.random.uniform(-1,1,size=(1,10))
plt.bar(range(len(vec)), vec, linewidth=1)
```

This code always raises

```
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

when doing something relating to `linewidth`, no matter what value I pass in or if at all.

My matplotlib version is 2.1.0. What can be the problem here? The API for `bar` seems straightforward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `vec` a 1-dimensional array:

```
vec = np.random.uniform(-1,1,size=10)
```

---

`vec = np.random.uniform(-1,1,size=(1,10))` makes `vec` a 2D array with shape (1, 10) -- i.e. an array with 1 row and 10 columns. [`plt.bar`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html) expects `height` to be either a constant or 1D sequences of scalars.

> ```
> height : scalar or sequence of scalars
>          the height(s) of the bars
> ```

---

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
vec = np.random.uniform(-1,1,size=10)
plt.bar(range(len(vec)), vec, linewidth=1)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This is such idiocy it hurts. Please accept my upvote whilst I bang my head on the table.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to plot a two-dimensional array. It expects a 1-D array
Here's edited code to work

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
vec = np.random.uniform(-1,1,size=(10)) #changed the size part
plt.bar(range(len(vec)), vec, linewidth=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here `vec = np.random.uniform(-1,1,size=(1,10))` creates an array of shape `(1,10)`. The error tells you that the array to supply to `bar` should be 1D, not 2D.

The straight forward solution is to not create a 2D array in the first place.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
vec = np.random.uniform(-1,1,size=(10))

plt.bar(range(len(vec)), vec, linewidth=1)
plt.show()
```

If you already have such an array, the solution would be to select the first (and only) row from it to plot.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
vec = np.random.uniform(-1,1,size=(1,10))
vec1D= vec[0]
plt.bar(range(len(vec1D)), vec1D, linewidth=1)
plt.show()
```